# What is the Segmentation fault (core dumped) error?

Tags: ros, gazebo7, ros-kinetic, nvidia

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm using ROS kinetic of Ubuntu 16.04, and the Gazebo version is 7.

My work is related to Deep Reinforcement Learning, and I'm doing it with the Gazebo simulation.

And I've also DONE HAVE NVIDIA Geforce 1080 and graphic driver on my laptop.

But I'm getting the error saying,

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I really don't have any idea and googled it and I think this might be because of Nvidia GPU according to [this guy](https://answers.ros.org/question/281376/gazebo-is-crashingsegmentation-fault/)

However, I've already had Nvidia graphic card!!

Just so you know, when I did

> $ sudo apt-get update

I got some errors that I'm not still familiar with,

```
W: Target Packages (Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-cuda.list:1
W: Target Translations (en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-cuda.list:1
W: Target Translations (en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-cuda.list:1
W: Target Packages (Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-cuda.list:1
W: Target Translations (en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-cuda.list:1
W: Target Translations (en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-cuda.list:1
```

So I removed `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-cuda.list` and re-update and sudo apt-get upgrade, but it still does NOT work...

I can bring up a gazebo, but it stops by itself without my order at a certain moment.

Anyone, who is familiar with this kind of error?

Thanks in advance :)

--

P.S.

I re-post this issue because an hour passed from when I posted this issue firstly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351463/what-is-the-segmentation-fault-(core-dumped)-error?/) by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2020-05-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-05**:
This reads like a duplicate of #q351440.

If it is, please don't post more duplicates.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-05-05**:
I don’t see how this is ROS related. These issues seem vendor specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following [this guy](https://answers.ros.org/question/281376/gazebo-is-crashingsegmentation-fault/), I've launched so far **9 times** and this is **10 times,** and it looks it goes well on some levels.

To anyone who already has corresponded NVIDIA driver, I'de like to recommend re-launch until it works.

Thank you :)

---

Originally posted by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) with karma: 195 on 2020-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0